# setFilterIfMissing not working in hbase shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hbase

I have hbase shell query which works correctly in power shell using hbase shell:

`scan 'table', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnFilter('ids','author_ids','=','regexstring:.*USER123.*',true,true)`

I'm trying to rewrite the same to the shell script that can be run from the command line in the background using &, but setFilterIfMissing not working - records where specific column is missing are also presented in the output, not sure why

```
echo scan "'table', {FILTER=>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('ids'),Bytes.toBytes('author_ids'),org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RegexStringComparator.new('.*USER123.*')).setFilterIfMissing(true)}" | hbase shell -n > output.out
```

your help will be much appreciated

Comment: Do you realize you use 2 different commands? The first command doesn't match what follows `echo`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk In second command I have to use full links to classes as without this links classess are not recognized and there is an error that command not found